# Why is there a Pi specific version of Ubuntu, and we can't just install regular Ubuntu ARM?

Tags: raspberrypi

Coming from the perspective of "normal" machines (i.e. consumer desktops/laptops) you can just download the x86-64 and it will work on the machine regardless of the particular components (so long as the processor architecture matches).

The Pi (to my non-expert eyes) is an ARM machine, so why is there a specific build for the Pi when it still targets ARM architecture?

Thanks!

Comment: There is not a single ARM architecture; there is *armhf*, *arm64* for r.pi's.  Raspberry pi's are low-end devices with more limitations than a high-end ARM processors, but even intel have IA64 (intel only & mostly EOL), x86/i386-i686 & amd64 (x86-64 as you listed it).  There is greater choice for Ubuntu Core or enterprise/device geared use than the consumer grade (r.pi) products...

Comment: Ah so it is due to a slightly different architecture, I see. On the Ubuntu ARM download page, it doesn't seem to explicitly mention architecture, which makes me think a certain ARM instruction set is the "de facto" one. Is this the case, and if so which?

Comment: Intel make their own CPUs (now to AMD64 or AMD's x86_64 compatible instruction set as IA64 was a failure in the marketplace due to no x86 compatibility) and have a limited range of product. ARM Holdings however design processors, allowing people to buy a product & change it, then have another company make it. These chip producers may provide ARM based products, but they are not all fully compatible with each other (core instructions are common though), ie. a far more fragmented market exists for ARM (and our ARM based android phones)...

Comment: See also https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2444356

Comment: Thanks for the information! Hmm, that's not me. Did someone take my question and repost it, or is there automation such that posts from here get posted to that forum?

Comment: fyi:  when I said ARM Holding & buy a 'product' - their product is the *design* of a 
a processor, and not the processor itself, as they don't have fabricating plants capable of making processors.  This site and UF are not linked

Answer (score 0):

At http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/releases/bionic/release/ you can see versions that are identified as specific for Hard Float or generic :-

Raspberry Pi 3 (Hard-Float) preinstalled server image 
For modern Raspberry Pi boards (Pi 2, Pi 3 and Pi 4).
Raspberry Pi 3 (64-bit ARM) preinstalled server image